# Why am I getting "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682016/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast)
>   [assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430909/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast)

I'm currently learning C and struggling a bit. I'm making a program that loops through an array of questions and populates an array of answers. I keep getting the following warning:

```
/var/Cprograms/quiz.c|24|warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|
```

I'm still trying to grasp the use of pointers and I may be using them completely wrong but that's why I'm here to learn. So I need help figuring what I'm doing wrong on line 24 in order to get the program working and eventually get it to print out the answers. Here's the code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Yes or no Question Quiz:
get answers from command prompt
and print answers at end of session
using pointers
*/

/* char *gets(char *s) */

void loopQuiz (void)
 {
     char *questions[] = {"Is true == true?", "Is 0 == 1?", "Does water have atleast 3 phases?", "Is C a programming language?"};
     char *answers[3];


     int i = 0;
     int count = sizeof(questions) / sizeof(int);

     do
      {
          printf("%s \n", questions[i]);
          answers[i] = getchar();
          i++;
      }
     while (i < count);

    /*print function to go here*/
 }



int main (void)
 {
     loopQuiz();
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: In the future, please make sure your question titles are less generic. People generally look for questions they know how to solve, and that's easier to do if the title tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Please do not "fix" the error in the example code. It is really hard to spot an error that has been edited away.

Comment: Gee, do you think it might be possible to do a search before you ask? The only problem here is knowing *which* of the zillion duplicates to choose.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *answers[3];
```

`answers` is an array of 3 pointer to char.

```
answers[i] = getchar();
```

Attempts to assign an int to `answers[i]`.  Your types are wrong.  `getchar` returns an `unsigned char` converted to an int (unless you hit `EOF`), so what you want is...

```
char answers[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

(You owe me a donation for counting until the 24th line in your code...)

The problem is on this line:

```
answers[i] = getchar();
```

Since `answers` is an array of `char *`, but you assign an `int` (the return value of `getchar()`) to one of its members, this is an invalid assignment. I don't see what you expect this to do, but it is certainly wrong. You need to assign a `char *` to `answers[i]`.

Comment: It's possible they mean to make answers an array of char (`char answers[3]`), but then there's still the issue of assigning an int to a char.

Comment: @BrendanLong You can assign an `int` to a `char` (since they're both integral types) as long as the value of that `int` fits into a `char`. This is always a case when the `int` is returned by `getchar()` and it's not `EOF`.

Comment: @BrendanLong: The docs for `getchar` stats that it returns an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`.

Comment: @EdS. Unless it's EOF (I think EOF == -1?). Since they're not checking for EOF, the cast from char to int is invalid.

Comment: @BrendanLong Isn't that what I just wrote?

Comment: Did not realize getchar() returns an int. In that case should I be using fgets()?

Comment: @FrancisBailey No. `char` is often treated as `int` in C. Get used to it.

Comment: @FrancisBailey Using `getchar` is fine, but you need to check for `EOF` before casting to a char.

Comment: @FrancisBailey Anyway, what exactly are you trying to accomplish by assigning that array char-by char? Do you need an array of `char`s or an array of strings (`char *`s)?

Comment: Well the goal is to populate the array of answers with a simpe "Y" or "N"

Comment: @BrendanLong: Yeah, you're right.  It should be `char`, not `unsigned char`.  It returns and `unsigned char` in normal instances unless `EOF` is hit (which is why it returns an `int` in the first place)

Comment: @FrancisBailey Then you need a `char array[size];`, not `char *array[size];`.

Comment: Okay so I did change the code to char array[size] but valgrind tells me answers is set but unused now

Comment: @FrancisBailey That's because you're assigning variables to it, but you're not doing anything with the result. Once you start doing whatever it is you plan to do with it, that warning will go away.

Comment: Okay I appreciate the help, I probably bit off more than I could chew so I'll go back to the studying.

Comment: @FrancisBailey Yes, that's a smart thing to do :)

Answer (score 1):

```
answers[i] = getchar();
```

`getchar()` returns an `int`, but

```
char *answers[3];
```

`answers` is declared as an array of pointers, so you're assigning an integer to a pointer without casting, just as the error message says.